# Background moving different speeds XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, background-image, pacman

This is so odd, and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I am working on a weird pacman clone, where you are zoomed in and the map randomly generates. Its essentially a maze game.

My issue is that when I generate the map, and then have the map move rather than the player (keeping the player in the center of the screen, the peices of the map are moving at different speeds. I have an array (9x9) that holds different pieces of the map. Each piece is an .png file. The .png's are picture I made of a black path and blue walls.

I have a series of 11 of these (each a different shape). When the map generates they each are given a position relative to the center (where the player starts) corresponding to their location in the array. When the player moves so should the image in the screen, and then the Location of the rest change relative to the movement. It draws only the pieces visible to the player to make the game run smoother.

here is the code for movement:

```
public void Update(GameTime gametime, Player player, KeyboardState keyboard, Rectangle mainFrame)
{
    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    {
        player.fakePosition.X -= 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                board[i, j].X += board[i, j].speed;
    }

    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    {
        player.fakePosition.X += 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                board[i, j].X -= board[i, j].speed;
    }

    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    {
        player.fakePosition.Y -= 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                board[i, j].Y += board[i, j].speed;
    }

    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
    {
        player.fakePosition.Y += 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                board[i, j].Y -= board[i, j].speed;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            if (board[i, j].visibleBox.Intersects(mainFrame))
                board[i, j].Visible = true;
}
```

from what I've noticed, the higher up on the draw (the further into the list (because Im drawing them all on top of each other at the start for testing purposes) the faster it moves. But they should all be moving at the same speed (which is equal to 5)

If you have any questions let me know!

Comment: Are you setting the same `.speed` value for all board pieces?

Comment: @Joe yeah its set as a public variable for easier access (cuz im lazy) within the Piece class. Its set to 5 upon construction and never modified after that.

Answer (score 0):

Are these .speed all the same? I'm not sure whether this may help, but if the boards are relative static to each other all the time, maybe you can put all the boards under a 'root', and each board holds the relative position to the 'root'. Then you can move the world by changing the position of 'root', and get the absolute position of a board by root.position + board[i,j].position. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, the speed value is help in the Piece class. This class also holds the position. My issue is that when I set them all to draw at (0, 0) (on to op each other) they move at different speeds (faster the later it was drawn (closest to the top of the screen) and it is even worse when I try to draw the map like it is supposed to be.